# telnet code java from org.apache not working with windows7

Tags: java, windows-7, telnet

I am using a sample telnet application code using package org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient

When i run this in XP, telnet session is connected and i can retrieve data from it.

But When i run the same jar in Windows7, its failed with below exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
javax/net/SocketFactory

I first used jre7 and then updated both jar and windows7 to jre6, but no positive results

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

There is something seriously wrong with your Java installation. That class was introduced in about 2004. Check which java.exe you are actually running. What does java -version display?

Comment: it shows 1.7.05 version, but upgrading to jre7 it shows different error. system error 193, Failed to load driver for microsoft access driver(*.mdb) in windows7. Having any idea how to use jar file created in XP to use in windows7? we need to recompile in windows 7?